# Проверка количество запросо в соеденении

Tags: база-данных, node.js, cassandra

При обращении к cassandra переодически вылетает така ошибка

> InternalServerError: {"message":"All host(s) tried for query failed.
>   First host tried, 127.0.0.1:9042: BusyConnectionError: All connections
>   to host 127.0.0.1:9042 are busy, 2048 requests are in-flight on a
>   single connection. See innerErrors."

Есть ли способ посмотеть статус запросов в соеденении?
Увеличивать пул пробывал - не помогает.
Использую Node js и cassandra-driver

Comment: какая версия драйвера?

Answer (score 0):

Можно получить текущую информацию о состоянии пула соединений к каждому хосту - просто использовать функцию `getState()` созданного клиента.  Вот пример из [документации](https://docs.datastax.com/en/developer/nodejs-driver/4.0/features/connection-pooling/#get-status-of-the-connection-pool):

```
const state = client.getState();
for (let host of state.getConnectedHosts()) {
  console.log('Host %s: open connections = %d; in flight queries = %d',
    host.address, state.getOpenConnections(host), state.getInFlightQueries(host));
}
```

Насчет увеличения количества запросов - как это производилось? Это стандартная функциональность и она не может быть сломана :-) Я подозреваю что пытались увеличить больше чем разрешенные 32к запросов (этого нет в документации к nodejs драйверу, но есть в [документации к java driver](https://docs.datastax.com/en/developer/java-driver/3.6/manual/pooling/)).